# AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest sourceFrameByTrackID nil for video with alpha

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avvideocomposition, avcomposition

I'm trying to add some transparent animation videos to my composition as a transition but in my custom compositor (`AVVideoCompositing`) when I try to get pixel buffer via
`AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest.sourceFrame` it returns nil. If I use non transparent H.264 (mp4) video it works. Transparent video (mov) is encoded with Timecode and Apple ProRes 4444.

Should I try with HEVC? I've seen some suggestions to use Chroma CIFilter on non-transparent video to remove the background, but I'm not sure if that's a right approach.

The desired effect for animated transitions could be seen [here](https://www.magisto.com/video/MUYdOwFVBCw-WQdgCzE?l=vsm&o=w&c=c).

Comment: Usually what is done here is to embed the alpha channel in the non-alpha supporting format (like h264) next to/above/above/below the colour channels, and then use the GPU to create RGBA output, suitable to return from `AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest.sourceFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

ProRes is actually not supported on iOS. However, you should be able to use `CMVideoCodecType.hevcWithAlpha` for your use case.

To get a list of available encoders, you can do the following:

```
import VideoToolbox

var encoders: CFArray?
VTCopyVideoEncoderList(nil, &encoders)
print(encoders!)
```